# Query function with Lambda and DynamoDB

Tags: jquery, json, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Newbie for `dynamodb` and trying to get new lambda function to query table.

Can someone help me out and tell me what is wrong with the son that I am passing to the .query function.  Client_ID is my hash key on the table(String)

```
{
    "TableName": "table1",
     "KeyConditions": {
        "Client_ID": {
            "ComparisonOperator": "EQ",
            "AttributeValueList":[
                {"S": "12345"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When testing i get error back

```
"errorMessage": "Need to pass in a valid Condition Object."
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the DynamoDB Document SDK or low level SDK? It seems like you are using the Document SDK (https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk), in which case you should use the Condition object instead to specify the Key Conditions (i.e. KeyConditions = [docClient.Condition("Client_ID", "EQ", "12345")]) . An easier way to specify KeyConditions is to use the KeyConditionsExpression parameter instead (documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression). Then your params would look like:

`{
    "TableName": "table1",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "Client_ID = :str",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":str": "12345"}
}`